# Why is Page Reloading in-spite of specifying return false command in Java Script?

Tags: javascript, telerik, modal-dialog

I have a javascript which is used to display a modal popup. Once the modal is displayed the page is reloading. To stop the page from reloading I tried using the `return false` statement inside my function, but it didn't work. I also tried specifying `return false` inside `OnClientClick` button but, it's still not working.

Can any one tell what are the other reasons because of which the page is reloading?

JavaScript:

```
function showWindow() {
        var wnd = $find("<%=RadWindow1.ClientID %>");
        wnd.show();
       //return false;         
       }
```

Rad Window and Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Remove"  CommandName="Split"  OnClientClick="showWindow(); return false"/>
```

```
<ContentTemplate>
    Enter a reason to delete:<br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ReasonTextBox" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" 
        Width="350"/> <br/>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="DeleteButton" Text="Delete"/>
</ContentTemplate>
</telerik:RadWindow>
```

Comment: What does your generated markup look like?

Comment: @bfavaretto Well, I already did that. Its sill not working and that's my question actually.

Comment: Okay, that wasn't clear. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Your code worked for me with Telerik AJAX 2013Q2..  Here is the source I used in an effort to replicate your issue:  https://gist.github.com/csharpfritz/76990cb719c44d0d7d78#file-modalwindow-aspx

Comment: Thanks Jeff. What do you think might the issue with my website then? Can Master Page cause this reload? However,I don't see anything secific to my problem.